# background-image path css

Tags: css, url, path, background, background-image

I am having trouble to put a background-image on my website.

[image]

This is a Google Maps.
So then I put a background-color (behind it): red; just to show you all what is going on:

```
section.middle{
background-color: red;
```

}

[image: redbackground]

But when I put a background-image it doens't show correctly:

```
section.middle{
background-image: url(/public/css/img/gymbackgroundhome.jpg);
```

}

[image: nobackgroundimage]

This is my workspace:

[image: workspace]

Thank you!

Comment: First off, you need quotes around your class `middle`, like this:  `<section class="middle">`

Comment: Woops! I forgot that. By the way, it didn't change any effect. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: None. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: What are the image dimensions? Have you tried [`background-size`?](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I have tried. No effects :(. I am totally sure that the path is wrong. Don't know why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url()` value in `css` has to be between quotes:

```css
section.middle{
    background-image: url("/public/css/img/gymbackgroundhome.jpg");
}
```

Comment: It wasn't me. I am going to vote positive and neutral that. Thanks for trying to help, but it didn't do any changes.

Comment: @DanielCassianoChaves It was not intended for you ;) Are sure of the path of your image according to the html file where you load this styles?

Comment: Kind of. It just doesn't pick the image as I ask for. And as I put the workspace upside, I would say that the path is right. I tried to change the whole background, CSSing the  whole html{} and happens the same thing. Just the colors change and the image cannot be picked up.

Comment: Good way to debug will be to try with a valid image path: `background-image: url("https://www.google.fr/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");`

Comment: Thank you for that! It works. The problem is the path. Can't find why, but I am going to still trying.

Comment: @DanielCassianoChaves Well nice that we found the problem ;) Would be nice to `upvote` this answer to tell to next reader that there is a reflexion here ;)

Comment: @DanielCassianoChaves Not a problem ;) Can you please `upvote` it too ? :)